# Is a union more efficient than a shift on modern compilers?

Tags: c, performance, compiler-optimization, unions, shift

Consider the simple code:

```
UINT64 result;
UINT32 high, low;
...
result = ((UINT64)high << 32) | (UINT64)low;
```

Do modern compilers turn that into a real barrel shift on high, or optimize it to a simple copy to the right location?

If not, then using a union would seem to be more efficient than the shift that most people appear to use.  However, having the compiler optimize this is the ideal solution.

I'm wondering how I should advise people when they do require that extra little bit of performance.

Comment: I'd advise them to try both, and time them. It's very difficult to predict the code compilers will emit, and even more difficult to predict how "efficient" it will be.

Comment: I think you mean a bitwise `or` (`|`), not a logical `or` (`||`).

Comment: It is also easy to predict that simple one line "optimizations" are already well known to the compiler writers, and will hardly ever make a difference. If you are hard pressed on performance, by all means try it, but don't hold your breath!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the following (hopefully valid) test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(uint64_t x);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef UNION
  union {
    uint64_t full;
    struct {
      uint32_t low;
      uint32_t high;
    } p;
  } result;
  #define value result.full
#else
  uint64_t result;
  #define value result
#endif
  uint32_t high, low;

  if (argc < 3) return 0;

  high = atoi(argv[1]);
  low = atoi(argv[2]);

#ifdef UNION
  result.p.high = high;
  result.p.low = low;
#else
  result = ((uint64_t) high << 32) | low;
#endif

  // printf("%08x%08x\n", (uint32_t) (value >> 32), (uint32_t) (value & 0xffffffff));
  func(value);

  return 0;
}
```

Running a diff of the unoptimized output of `gcc -s`:

```
<   mov -4(%rbp), %eax
<   movq    %rax, %rdx
<   salq    $32, %rdx
<   mov -8(%rbp), %eax
<   orq %rdx, %rax
<   movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
---
>   movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
>   movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
>   movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
>   movl    %eax, -16(%rbp)
```

I don't know assembly, so it's hard for me to analyze that. However, it looks like some shifting is taking place as expected on the non-union (top) version.

But with optimizations `-O2` enabled, the output was identical. So the same code was generated and both ways will have the same performance.

(gcc version 4.5.2 on Linux/AMD64)

Partial output of optimized `-O2` code with or without union:

```
    movq    8(%rsi), %rdi
    movl    $10, %edx
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    call    strtol

    movq    16(%rbx), %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rbp
    movl    $10, %edx
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    call    strtol

    movq    %rbp, %rdi
    mov     %eax, %eax
    salq    $32, %rdi
    orq     %rax, %rdi
    call    func
```

The snippet begins immediately after the jump generated by the `if` line.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what code is generated, what matters is how fast the generated code runs - you need to time it.

Comment: @Neil, correct. Let's assume a union is faster, for discussion's sake. My point is simply that if you use a union expecting faster results, it doesn't matter because the compiler has "optimized" it to the same thing as a shift.

Comment: When you say the output was identical - which version did it choose for the optimized version, the one that consisted only of moves, or the one with the shift (salq) ? They both consist of 4 moves, so I would assume the optimized version would be the 4 moves alone, getting rid of the extra two operations.

Comment: @Adam, I've included the optimized version. (The C source code was changed to just call an arbitrary external function to minimize the extra code generated by the printf parameters.) I don't know enough to tell whether the `strtol` calls are being placed directly in the final destination or not, but it looks to me like there's four operations involving a shift. Anyway, I only wrote this for curiosity's sake... Obviously this is a single trivial instance of the broader question, but it does show that the generated code /might/ be the same. Categorically, my answer would be what @fortran said.

Comment: Interesting!  It chose the barrel shifted version as the optimized version.  That makes sense as it leaves the result in a register for further use, and the two register operations (shift and or) are both cheaper than memory moves. That makes sense now that I think about it further.  Thank you for performing the work to find out!

Answer (score 4):

Modern compilers are smarter than what you might think ;-) (so yes, I think you can expect a barrel shift on any decent compiler).

Anyway, I would use the option that has a semantic closer to what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

If this supposed to be platform independent then the only option is to use shifts here.

With `union { r64; struct{low;high}}` you cannot tell on what low/high fields will map to. Think about endianess.

Modern compilers are pretty good handling such shifts.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: This response is based on an earlier version of the OP's code that did not have a cast*

This code

```
result = (high << 32) | low;
```

is actually going to have undefined results ... since with `high` you're shifting a 32-bit value by 32-bits (the width of the value), the results are going to be undefined and will depend on how a compiler and OS platform decide to handle the shift.  The results of that undefined shift will then be or'd with `low`, which again will be undefined since you're or'ing an undefined value against a defined value, and so the end-result will most likely not be a 64-bit value like you want.  For instance, the code emitted by `gcc -s` on OSX 10.6 looks like:

```
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax      //retrieving the value of "high"
movl    $32, %ecx          
shal    %cl, %eax           //performing the 32-bit shift on "high"
orl    -8(%rbp), %eax       //OR'ing the value of "low" to the shift op result
```

So you can see that the shift is only taking place on a 32-bit value in a 32-bit register with a 32-bit assembly command ... the results end up being the exact same as `high | low` without any shifting at all because in this case, `shal $32, %eax` just returns the value that was originally in `EAX`.  You're not getting a 64-bit result.

In order to avoid that, cast `high` to a `uint64_t` like:

```
result = ((uint64_t)high << 32) | low;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info ... adjusting my answer above

Comment: Yes, I removed the casting for brevity.  Due to the number of comments on how it needs to be properly cast I see I should have left it in.

Comment: No problem ... I'll be more than happy to delete this post if you add back in the cast, otherwise I think it will be good to leave it so that someone doesn't try the code above as-is right now and then scratch their heads wondering why it doesn't quite work as expected.  BTW, I did give you a +1 since I think overall this is a great question (and I learned something myself :-)

Comment: Go ahead and leave your answer, even though I have added the casting back in.